# How to run bash commands in gulp?

Tags: bash, gulp

I want to add some bash commands at the end of `gulp.watch` function to accelerate my development speed. So, I am wondering if it is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-shell.

> A handy command line interface for gulp

Comment: While there are alternative ways (like gulp-exec and gulp-spawn), the gulp-shell prints the output from the command immediately - which is often wanted.

Comment: There is now also [`gulp-run`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-run), which has a cleaner and more intuitive interface, IMO.

Comment: gulp-shell is blacklisted, see https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json.

Comment: It is "blacklisted" because there is some overlap with `gulp-exec` -- not that there is anything wrong with either plugin.  https://github.com/sun-zheng-an/gulp-shell/issues/1

Comment: gulp-run is also blacklisted. Taken reference from same link so option are gulp-exec or gulp-spawn only.

Comment: One doesn't need any plugins to run bash commands from gulp. Just use node's `child_process` directly. This why those plugins get blacklisted.

Comment: Regarding the comment about gulp-shell printing the output from the command immediately:  `child_process.spawn` also prints out the output immediately, **if** you add the event handlers as shown in the answer from @Mangled Deutz.

Answer (score 77):

I would go with:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var fancyLog = require('fancy-log');
var beeper = require('beeper');

gulp.task('default', function(){

    gulp.watch('*.js', function(e) {
        // Do run some gulp tasks here
        // ...

        // Finally execute your script below - here "ls -lA"
        var child = spawn("ls", ["-lA"], {cwd: process.cwd()}),
            stdout = '',
            stderr = '';

        child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

        child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            stdout += data;
            fancyLog(data);
        });

        child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
        child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            stderr += data;
            fancyLog.error(data));
            beeper();
        });

        child.on('close', function(code) {
            fancyLog("Done with exit code", code);
            fancyLog("You access complete stdout and stderr from here"); // stdout, stderr
        });


    });
});
```

Nothing really "gulp" in here - mainly using child processes http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html and spoofing the result into fancy-log

Comment: After doing some research on child processes, I'v achieved my goal by using `child_process.exec` at last. Thanks for your node resource!

Comment: Thank you for actually addressing his question instead of responding with a link to a plugin.

Comment: While I can understand how you might not want to use a plugin, I believe my answer still addressed the question.

Comment: I had the same question and your answer better met my needs than a re-engineering of this proverbial wheel (not to detract anything from Mangled's answer).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is as easy as:

```
var child = require('child_process');
var gulp   = require('gulp');

gulp.task('launch-ls',function(done) {
   child.spawn('ls', [ '-la'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
   done();
});
```

It doesn't use node streams and gulp pipes but it will do the work.

Comment: `done` is never called. Isn't this going to mess up script execution order if other scripts are supposed to run before or after it?

Comment: Yes, you are right @trusktr, thank you for the correction