# Execute arbitrary node script in gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

I want to run an `index.js` file as a part of my gulp process. I could add `node index.js` through something like gulp-shell as described in this thread ([How to run bash commands in gulp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128812/how-to-run-bash-command-in-gulp)) but it seems there should be an easier way.

I figured there would be a plugin called `gulp-node` or something to do this but it doesn't exist. How do others do it without turning your initial script into a gulp plugin, which seems intrusive?

Comment: Just use `require('./path/to/index')`.

Comment: @usandfriends if you want to add that as an answer with some more info for folks that you should insert that within a task I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `var data = require('./path/to/index')` to load/run the `index.js` module in your Gulp task and send any exported information to `data`. You can read more about `require` and Node.js modules [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules).

Comment: This doesn't work if you put that task within `gulp.watch`.

Comment: @mhkeller Yes, because `require` caches. You'll need to [delete the file from the cached files list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14801711).

Comment: Got it. Seems like a good candidate then for a gulp plugin to handle all that code then, unless there's some other solution.

Comment: [Gulp-load](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-load) looks like something that could be useful to you.