# Using gulp to run a asset download script

Tags: gulp

I have an isolated npm module with assets. I want to add gulp to this. Inside the project aside from my assets i have a bash script that downloads and updates my assets. I have been trying to find a way to create a gulp task that can run this script but i have not yet been able to get it to work. I tried the following and although it ran it did not run the script.

```
gulp.task('update-json', function(){
    gulp.src('assets/update_json.sh'); 
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to run bash command in gulp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128812/how-to-run-bash-command-in-gulp)

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to run an external script though-also gulp run is deprecated.